# How to convert FTPFile list to File List in Java?

Tags: java, file, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client

I have a list of FTP files and I can only convert the first `FTPFile` to `File`. I am using `org.apache.commons.net.ftp` library.
My code is works fine for the first time:

```
for (FTPFile file : files) {
  if(ftpClient.sendNoOp()){
   if(file.getName()!=null || !file.getName().equals("")) {
           InputStream iStream=ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());
           File file2 = File.createTempFile("xml", null);
           FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(iStream, file2);
           iStream.close();
                }
  }
}
```

From this code the loop traverse only time and the `FTPFile` is converted to `File` and after that it will get exception which is created by *`null`* value generated in `ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(file.getName())`.
Please help.

Comment: Take a look on what FTPFile.getName() returns. I suspect it returns the file name only and not the whole file path that, I assume, retrieveFileStream is expecting for.

Comment: It should be a name, there are no local files except the temp file. However, as far as I can see you are not closing the input stream? Perhaps you need to complete the first file transfer before you start a new one? Add a try-with-resources block and see if that helps.

Comment: FTPFile.getName() Gets the file name in evey loop ..and was working fine for the first loop or first file @rlm

Comment: @user2612030 I have closed the input stream and still geting the same error

Comment: Please catch the exception and write the file name for the failed file. It may be that you are trying to fetch a directory or some kind of special file that can't be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to finalize the transfer after you download the file. That is the reason you are able to download your first file and having issue with the download of second file.

```
 success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
 if (success) {
                System.out.println("File has been downloaded successfully.");
  }
```

If still issue persists, you can invoke ftpClient.getReplyCode() which will let you know why you are not able to download the file. Generally retrieveFileStream returns null when it cannot open the data connection

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have been stuck for day.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for `FTPClient#listFiles()`:

> **NOTE**: This array may contain null members if any of the individual file listings failed to parse. The caller should check each entry for null before referencing it.

You must check for null on each and every item returned in the array, otherwise  you will get NPEs.

Comment: Thanks, JIM Gorrison . i have checked, it Not retrieve null value in file

Comment: Please update the code in your original question to show what you have that checks for `null`.

Comment: i have update the code